# ViewState updates automatically while updating DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, viewstate

I am assigning a **DataTable** in a **ViewState**.

```
public void Method1()
{    
    DataTable dt = getData(); //Gets the Data

    ViewState["dtThis"] = dt;
}
```

Now when '***Method2***' executes **ViewState** will be assigned to **DataTable**.

```
public void Method2()
{    
    DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["dtThis"];

    dt2.Columns.Remove("FirstName");    //Removing a column

    dt2.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Now after the execution of the ***Method2*** when I check **(DataTable)ViewState("dtThis")** its having DataTable **dt2** even if I didn't assign **dt2** back to **ViewState("dtThis").** (means the column - "FirstName" is removed in the ViewSate("dtThis") DataTable).

Any idea why this type of behaviour of the ViewState?

And how to maintain the original ViewState ?

Comment: creating datatable copy using copy method of dt will help you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing reference of datatable into viewstate. So what ever updates done on `viewstate["dtThis"]` is directly affecting original Datatable obj assigned in `method1()`.

One way to preserve original view state datatable is to use DataTable.Copy() to create replica of original and operate on that replica

Comment: So what can be the solution?
Even I tried to a simple a=b; b=c; c=a; type method to maintain original values but it always gets updated in any case.

Comment: Does this apply to just DataTables in ViewState or would this apply if I had for example (perhaps a bad example) a List<T> in ViewState and updated an item in the List?

Comment: Considering how people could/would use ViewState, I can't believe that this behavior isn't highlighted Red anywhere ViewState is talked about. I just spent way too long trying to figure out why my viewstate[datatable] was getting clobbered until I came upon this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the reason but it also happened to me but at that time I was in a bit hurry, so I opted an alternate way. When I get datatable from ViewState, I made a new table and loop through records of original table and set values in new table :) so my viewstate table remained untouched.

Comment: I also tried that. like - DataTable dt1 = ViewState("dtThis");
DataTable dt_b = ViewState("dtThis");
//Remove columns from dt1;
ViewState("dtThis") = dt_b;
Then also dt_b and ViewState("dtThis") I got updated.

Comment: Do it like this:
DataTable dt1 = ViewState("dtThis");
    DataTable dt_b = new DataTable();

    Now loop through columns of dt1 and add those columns in dt_b and than move through rows of dt1 and add those rows in dt_b, thats how I made it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this and it solves referencing problem

```
DataTable dt2= ( (DataTable)ViewState["dtThis"]).Copy();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be memory hungry if the datatable is actually big? Because we are copying the DataTable ultimately and creating a new one.